# Чтение файлов с именами на кириллице по FTP

Tags: ftp

Есть такой код:

```
var enc = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251");
var requestUri = CreateRequestUri($"{_jobsDir}/{System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(jobName, enc)}.job");
var request = CreateFtpRequest(requestUri, WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile);

using (var response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{...}
```

Для файлов с именами на латинице, всё ОК. Для кириллических имен GetResponse выдает исключение:

```
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access).
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.RequestCallback(Object obj)
   at System.Net.CommandStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at System.IO.Stream.Close()
   at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream pooledStream)
   at System.Net.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(PooledStream pooledStream, Object owningObject, Int32 creationTimeout, Boolean canReuse)
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.FinishRequestStage(RequestStage stage)
   at System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()
```

Однако, если такой кирилличиский Url (который сгенерил CreateRequestUri) открыть в InternetExplorer-e, то файл читается.